# Curvature of a Convex Plane Curve

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

I'm having trouble with part b) this question (image is below) from a set of notes I'm studying from. I think there may be a mistake as it seems to me that $p(\theta)+p''(\theta)=0$ by its definition. I also calculated that $\alpha' \times \alpha''=0$ which would mean its curvature would be zero since for a general curve $\kappa=\frac{|\alpha'\times \alpha''|}{|\alpha|^3}$. Not sure if I've interpreted this question incorrectly and if there is a mistake in part b) what would it's curvature be as I'm a but stumped here. Thanks.[image]

Comment: By differentiating twice $\mathbb{\alpha}(\theta)$ I get exactly the result reported in the book. Why do you say that $p(\theta)+p''(\theta)=0$?

Comment: I know I am differentiating it incorrectly, how did you differentiate the equation?

Comment: As Raskolnikov points out, $p(\theta)$ is a *given* function, you must leave it "as is" together with its derivatives. For instance: $$\alpha'(\theta)=\bigl(-\sin\theta(p(\theta)+p''(\theta)), \cos\theta(p(\theta)+p''(\theta))\bigr).$$

Comment: I think I get it now, you can't just differentiate it and state $p'(\theta)$ explicity, all you can say is its derivative is $p'(\theta)$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you leave $p'(\theta)$ and $p''(\theta)$ as they are, you can easily obtain the stated results.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is in the fact that you take the derivative of equation

$$\cos(\theta)x+\sin(\theta)y=p(\theta)$$

with respect to theta. However, let's look closely at what this means. This equation represents a tangent line to the curve. For every choice of $\theta$, there is another tangent line. Hence the points $(x,y)$ that satisfy the equation depend on the choice of $\theta$.

When you take the derivative naïvely, what you do is act as if those points stay the same and you write:

$$-\sin(\theta)x+\cos(\theta)y=p'(\theta)$$

and then for the second derivative

$$-\cos(\theta)x-\sin(\theta)y=p''(\theta)$$.

But this is wrong. In the derivation process you really do a comparison between two different tangent lines and therefore you can't assume that the $(x,y)$ stays the same. Therefore, your conclusion that $p(\theta)+p''(\theta)=0$ is wrong.